# In selenium webdriver using c#, how to test a menu collapse and expand by clicking a button

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In `Selenium C#`, I'm trying to write a code that test when I `click` a menu button, the under menu collapses and expanded.

Any tips would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?? And add relevant HTML as well?? And let me know which option visible after expand and hide after hide after collapse. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I'm yet to write the code but wondering if i should use codes like:  theButtonElement.selectNode.IsExpanded(), and theButtonElement.selectNode.Collapse();. What about theButtonElement.show() and theButtonElement.Hide();? Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, If you want to verify whether particular element expanded or collapsed just check `.Displayed` property of that element as `element.Displayed`, if it returns true means element expanded other wise collapsed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Saurabh. Let me try and i will get back with my results. Have a pleasant day.

Answer (score 0):

> i'm trying to write a code that test when i click a menu button, the under menu collapses and expanded

If you want to verify whether particular element expanded or collapsed after clicking on menu button, just check [`IWebElement#Displayed`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Displayed.htm) property of that target element.

```
//Click on menu button element 

//Now find desire node to verify its expanded or collapsed 
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(..);
if(element.Displayed)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Expanded");
}else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Collapsed");
}
```